# How to reset custom request attribute on each request in Bottle?

Tags: python, python-3.4, bottle

Here's simplified version of my plugin:

```
class MyPlugin(object):
    ''' My plugin.
    '''

    api = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.time = datetime.now()

    def apply(self, callback, route):
        request.my_attr = self.time

        @wraps(callback)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            cb_response = callback(*args, **kwargs)
            return cb_response
        # Forget any cached values.
        route.reset()
        # Replace the route callback with the wrapped one.
        return wrapper

my_plugin = MyPlugin()

@route('/my_route', method=['GET', 'POST'], apply=[my_plugin])
def my_route():
    """ Http Handler.
    """
    response.content_type = 'text/txt;'
    time = request.my_attr
    print(time)

run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=DEBUG, quiet=QUIET)
```

It works with the first request, but fails with all subsequent requests:

```
# ./my_app.py
Bottle v0.12.9 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8888/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

2016-10-25 14:51:29.975600
46.101.xx.yy - - [25/Oct/2016 14:51:33] "POST /my_route HTTP/1.1" 200 1569
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1391, in __getattr__
    var = self.environ['bottle.request.ext.%s'%name]
KeyError: 'bottle.request.ext.my_attr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "./my_app.py", line 245, in wrapper
    cb_response = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./my_app.py", line 264, in my_route
    time = request.my_attr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1394, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError('Attribute %r not defined.' % name)
AttributeError: Attribute 'my_attr' not defined.
46.101.xx.yy - - [25/Oct/2016 14:51:37] "POST /my_route HTTP/1.1" 500 760
```

How do I reset `request.my_attr` on each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your end goal is, or what you mean precisely by "reset request.my_attr on each request" (since elsewhere you mention "cached values," which implies that you *do* intend to do some caching).  But it does seem clear that this line

```
request.my_attr = self.time
```

is in the wrong place.  You probably want to move that into your `wrapper` function, because (presumably) then intention is for that line to run on each request:

```
    @wraps(callback)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        request.my_attr = self.time
        cb_response = callback(*args, **kwargs)
        return cb_response
```

I'm not sure that makes sense to me, but I don't know what your goal is so maybe it is indeed what you intend.  In any case, moving the line into `wrapper` corrects the HTTP 500.  Hope that helps!  If not, please add a line or two describing what you're trying to accomplish and I'll try to help.

Comment: I simply wanted to init a custom object within the plugin body for every `request`, then attach it to the bottle `request` as an attribute and re-use that custom object in the http handler. Is there a better strategy of doing this? If there isn't - I will accept your answer, as moving `request.my_attr = self.time` inside the `wrapper` (before the `callback` call) essentially solved my problem. I used `route.reset()` to ensure that all plugins are re-applied, but now after a few more tests it seems that it's not actually needed.

Comment: Thanks, I see.  Yes, if you want your plugin to add to every request an attribute that can then be used in your route handler, then indeed you need to set it in `wrapper`.  `wrapper` is what gets called on every request (before your route handler).